# Mudar texto de uma div após clique no botão

Tags: javascript, html

Estou concluindo o design de um mini carrinho de compras.

Minha dúvida é, como fazer com que ao clicar em um botão altere o título e preço de duas divs. E outra, como mudar o botão de pagamento de acordo com o produto e os valores selecionado pelo usuário?

Link do protótipo: http://codepen.io/flashpremium/live/080ab885152ec081e10b5449eb2b26c4

Comment: Posta o seu código JS e o seu HTML... senão fica complicado rs

Comment: @MarllonNasser Segue o css, html e javascript no codepen: http://codepen.io/flashpremium/pen/080ab885152ec081e10b5449eb2b26c4

Comment: Olá @theflash ! Poderia adicionar a seu código aqui na SOpt? Isto facilita que irá pesquisar, e quem irá responder a sua pergunta! Caso haja dúvidas, por favor, [veja este link!](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1913/posso-mostrar-s%C3%B3-um-link-pro-meu-site-com-problemas). Desde já agredecemos!

Answer (score 5):

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="paragrafo">Clique no botão para mudar o texto</p>

<button onclick="funcao()">Clique aqui</button>

<script>
function funcao() {
    document.getElementById("paragrafo").innerHTML = "Pronto você mudou o texto (y)";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Espero que seja isso (Y).

Comment: É isso mesmo man! Valeu! Mas uma coisa, e como faria para mudar o botão do carrinho de compras de acordo com o clique em determinado botão?

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta ... foi mal ... pode perguntar dnv ... e tambem queria saber se posso usar o codigo que você tem ai, posso?

Comment: Já consegui resolver aqui. Qual código seria?